# How to query Mapbox MGLMapView features without visible map?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, augmented-reality

For an AR experience I'm working on, I want to have a "camera view" that shows annotations based on the user's location. If the user is in a certain area, show the annotation.

I'm able to do something like this using below

```
extension ViewController: AnnotationManagerDelegate {

func session(_ session: ARSession, cameraDidChangeTrackingState camera: ARCamera) {
    print("camera did change tracking state: \(camera.trackingState)")

    let annotationLocation = CLLocation()
    let point = CGPoint(x: annotationLocation.coordinate.longitude, y: annotationLocation.coordinate.latitude)
    let features = mapView.visibleFeatures(at: point);

    if let score = features.first(where: { $0.attributes["score"] as! Int >= 5 }) {
        // ...
```

But in my AR view, I want to hide the map - not show it. When I try setting `mapView.isHidden = true` - the query always fails.

This makes sense because the query is for *visible* features. How can instead hide the map, but still query tiles for features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Mapbox Studio https://www.mapbox.com/studio/ and create a new map style and remove all of the layers. You can style a Mapbox map to be a single solid color (land, water, roads, etc.), which is what you need. If you need to toggle between a map and a blank map, simply toggle between styles.

```
let basicMap = URL(string: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v9")
let blankMap = URL(string: "yourCustomURLFromMapboxStudio")
let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds, styleURL: blankMap)
```

Comment: Thanks - a step in the right direction, but I do need a layer with features. I set the layer's opacity to 0 and color to white, but it's still visible in the app.

Comment: I'm confused then as to what you need. You want the map's annotations to show without showing the map, correct? But the map cannot be a solid color, it must be transparent?

Comment: The annotations are AR features, not map features. The AR annotation depends on a user's location in the map-space.

Comment: There in lies the confusion, AR annotations not map annotations. Have you tried simply moving the map view off screen or behind a view layer?

Comment: Could you update your answer with a way to move off-screen? I'm very new to swift. I tried setting the map's opacity to 0, and toggled the `isHidden` flag to false, but those caused the query to return 0 features.

Comment: You can create a `UIView` that covers the entire map and then simply add things to that view as if it were the map. Or you can change the top constraint of the `mapView` to equal the bottom constraint of the view controller's view. Try one of those two and see how you like it.